# How to create a dump with Oracle PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I need to take dump of a user (including tables, procedures ,etc.) as `FILENAME.dmp`.

If I create a new user and import that `FILENAME.dmp`, then everything should be created.

How can I create this dump file?

Don't tel me to use the `Run > EXP` or `Run > IMP` functions because, due to some problem, that feature is not working for me.

Comment: imp is probably not working because of PATH issues. What happen if you run imp from the command line?

Comment: Actually, what you need is run exp, not imp.

Answer (score 23):

EXP (export) and IMP (import) are the two tools you need.  It's is better to try to run these on the command line and on the same machine.

*It can be run from remote, you just need to setup you `TNSNAMES.ORA` correctly and install all the developer tools with the same version as the database. Without knowing the error message you are experiencing then I can't help you to get exp/imp to work.*

The command to export a single user:

```
exp userid=dba/dbapassword OWNER=username DIRECT=Y FILE=filename.dmp
```

This will create the export dump file.

To import the dump file into a different user schema, first create the newuser in **SQLPLUS**:

```
SQL> create user newuser identified by 'password' quota unlimited users;
```

Then import the data:

```
imp userid=dba/dbapassword FILE=filename.dmp FROMUSER=username TOUSER=newusername
```

*If there is a lot of data then investigate increasing the `BUFFERS` or look into expdp/impdp*

*Most common errors for exp and imp are setup.  Check your `PATH` includes `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, check `$ORACLE_HOME` is set correctly and check `$ORACLE_SID` is set*

Comment: @Chandra Sekhar: How would Ibe able to do this from a remote machine? do I have to type the IP address? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: IIRC you would use the usual syntax for accessing a remote machine (like you would with SQLPLUS) i.e. userid=dba/password@remoteserver where 'remoteserver' has been defined in your TNSNAMES.ORA file.

Comment: I don't have rights to edit the TNSNAMES.ORA and the remoteserver entry is not present in the TNSNAMES.ora file. Now what do I do? :(

Comment: Ask for your LOCAL tnsnames.ora file to be amended. The tnsnames.ora file that needs to change is the one on the machine you are accessing from.  You don't need to change the tnsnames.ora on the database server.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to use the fully qualified form of the username/password@server syntax.  Sorry, but for that you'll have to hit the Oracle docs / Google (or look at asktom.oracle.com)

Answer (score 9):

Just to keep this up to date:

The current version of SQLDeveloper has an export tool (`Tools > Database Export`) that will allow you to dump a schema to a file, with filters for object types, object names, table data etc.

It's a fair amount easier to set-up and use than `exp` and `imp` if you're used to working in a GUI environment, but not as versatile if you need to use it for scripting anything.

Comment: Tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABJIIIE

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update this can be done by using Toad 9 also.Goto Database>Export>Data Pump Export wizard.At the desitination directory window if you dont find any directory in the dropdown,then you probably have to create a directory object.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY data_pmp_dir_test AS '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/pmp_dir_test';
```

See this for an [example](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/09/exporting-dump-using-data-pump-utility.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are some easy steps to make **Dump file** of your **Tables,Users and Procedures:**

> Goto sqlplus or any sql*plus
>   `connect by your username or password`

1. Now type host it looks like SQL>host.
2. Now type "exp" means export.
3. It ask u for username and password give the username and password of that user of which you want to make a dump file.
4. Now press Enter.
5. Now option blinks for Export file: EXPDAT.DMP>_ (Give a path and file name to where you want to make a dump file e.g e:\FILENAME.dmp) and the press enter
6. Select the option "Entire Database" or "Tables" or "Users" then press Enter
7. Again press Enter 2 more times table data and compress extent
8. Enter the name of table like i want to make dmp file of table student existing so type student and press Enter
9. Enter to quit now your file at your given path is dump file now import that dmp file to get all the table data.

Comment: Some of the file paths can be formatted like so: \`Filepath\`

Comment: Give a path means a destination where you want to place your dump file like in example I have used drive E so E:\any_name_of_file.dmp(extension)

Comment: No... I mean, in your answer, there is "e:\FILENAME.dmp", can you change it to \`e:\FILENAME.dmp\`, make sure to leave the `?

Comment: yes yes you can leave single quotes infact you can write it without any single or double quotes

Answer (score -1):

Export (or datapump if you have 10g/11g) is the way to do it. Why not ask how to fix your problems with that rather than trying to find another way to do it?