# How to create dump into separated files

Tags: oracle

In addition to [How to create a dump with Oracle PL/SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852261/how-to-create-a-dump-in-oracle-in-pl-sql-developer)

Is that possible to create a dump into separated files: I prefer the each stored object has its own file. So as result I want N files with views description (1 view per 1 file), M files with SP, O files with tables, etc

Is that possible?

**UPD**: i've found the answer in the current using oracle management tool we use - TOAD. so i decide to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.

I'd use DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to extract the "Create object" text, and UTL_FILE to write the text to a file on the database server. You need to decide whether you want indexes/constraints with the tables. With constraints, you'll get dependencies (ie table B has to be created before table A because of a referential integrity constraint).

It gets more complicated with triggers, types, procedures...

And then there's whether yo want the data or not.

Its very difficult to determine the order in which you'd have to run the files.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but seems like i will use the TOAD (that is used in my company for oracle management) for such purpose, due to it has at least 2 alternatives for accomplish the issue